# Javadoc Text Color Meaning

Tags: android, android-intent, javadoc

After over an hour of debugging, I realized that I had failed to instantiate an object before doing something that...well I'm still figuring out why I needed to instantiate it. Long story short, instantiating the object fixed the bug in my program.

What was happening was that I was starting an activity with startActivityForResult and passing an intent with values...after fixing the problem and trying to find why I needed to instantiate my object, I came across this RED TEXT in the javadoc (see the screenshot below). Why is the text red? What does it mean? I feel this would help me play detective and find the true source of my error. Thanks!

[image: http://imgur.com/8RBB6R5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking at is not javadoc, it's a pop-up version of the Eclipse "Variables View", which you can also see during a debug session by going to View --> Show Window --> Debug --> Variables.

The variables view has these default text colors:
[image]

From this, we can determine that the red text you're seeing means the `mMap` variable you're looking at was recently updated. In the screenshot you posted, the process is paused on a specific line of code (the green one `et.setSelect...`) and between wherever you were previously paused and the current breakpoint the `mMap` variable's value has been changed.